# Order and isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields

> Question:
>   The non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{3}\left [ i \right ]$ form an abelian group of order 8 under multiplication. 
>   Is it isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{8},\mathbb{Z}_{4}\bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

I think the stratagem is to find the number of orders for each elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}\left [ i \right ]$ and for all the other groups. Since Isomorphism demands bijection, if the number of elements in the other groups equals to that of the number of elements of certain order in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}\left [ i \right ]$, we are done.

Note: $\mathbb{Z}_{3}\left [ i \right ]=\left \{1,2,i,1+i,2+i,2i,1+2i,2+2i \right \}$

There is a duplicate thread on this but I felt the solution odd. Nonetheless I have left a comment on that thread.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general the units of a finite field form a cyclic group under multiplication.

Comment: We can rule out $\mathbb Z_4\bigoplus\mathbb Z_4$ because that's not a group of order $8.$ Was that a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $\langle 1+i\rangle$:

$$(1+i) \mapsto (2i) \mapsto (1+2i) \mapsto (2) \mapsto (2+2i) \mapsto (i) \mapsto (2+i) \mapsto (1)$$

Hence $\Bbb Z_3[i]$ is cyclic, and is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_8$.